# What is a "theta-prime dimensional fractal topology"?

Tags: general-topology, fractals, popular-math

In a story I read, a conceptual entity(it was an idea with sentiency, but thats besides the point) was described as a "theta-prime dimensional fractal topology". Is this gobbledygook or is there any math behind it?

I saw this in the book "There is no Antimemetic Division" by QNTM.

Comment: I find it hard to believe there was no further context or explanation. Is theta a variable or a word?

Comment: But fractal dimension is very much a thing

Comment: @FShrike, theta prime was represented as a symbol.

Comment: Fractal alongside topology seems a bit suspect but if you replace topology with geometry then this is a perfectly sensible concept, and there might be a way to interpret it with topology there, I'm not enough of an expert in this area to say.

Comment: What would the theta-prime part mean?

Comment: @NielIGuess Well without further information, I would assume it just refered to some constant (for example $\theta'=1.5$).

Comment: Without knowing where you saw this, it is impossible to answer the question.  That being said "fractal" is one of those words (like "quantum" or "crypto") which has been caught up into the zeitgeist, and is often used in non-mathematical contexts as a kind of techno-babble.  If you saw this in the context of fiction, it is almost certainly nonsense.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I saw it in the book "There is no antimemetics divison". It was an SCP story, but I didn't know theta-prime was scp-033

Answer (score 4):

The "theta-prime" is a reference to [SCP-033](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-033):

> Description: SCP-033 appears as a field of complex mathematical symbols ranging from simple layman-identifiable representations to those only interpretable by highly-trained mathematicians. The "sum" of the symbols is equal to a previously unknown integer (designated **Theta Prime** [emphasis mine] by Prof. Hutchinson) of intermediate value between █ and █.

The reference to fractals, in combination with the reference to dimensions, could be thought of as a reference to [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension), which is a way to assign non-integer dimensions to fractals. However, it's worth clarifying that Hausdorff dimension is not a *topological* concept, the way mathematicians use that word; it relies crucially on *metric* structure, meaning the ability to measure distances.

"$d$-dimensional fractal *geometry*" could be meaningfully interpreted in terms of Hausdorff dimension. Non-mathematicians frequently use "topology" or "topological" in a different and looser sense than the meaning that term has in mathematics, which is quite specific.

Of course $\theta'$ does not exist. (But I *would* say that, wouldn't I...)

Comment: The humour bit is *"a previously unknown **integer** [...] of **intermediate** value."*